# solving a minimization problem using scipy.optimize in python

Tags: python, optimization

I have a question regarding solving a minimization problem using `scipy.optimize` in python. I have an 1-D array (`x`) containing about 2000 elements as the variables of this problem, and a `list` of `{constraint,dict}`elements as the constraints of the optimization problem.
The issue is that I want to calculate the sum of a large number of variables within a `for` loop to define objective function and the constraints. I have attached a simple example of my code below, but it should be considered that according to the complication of my code, it is not possible to do the calculation without `for` loops. However, by doing this, I face with this error: `'function' object is not iterable`.

```
def objective(x):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        sum += x[i]
    return sum

def constraints(x):
    constraint = []
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        sum = 0
        for j in range(1, 100):
            sum += j*x[i]
        constraint.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': 10 - sum})
    return constraint
sol = minimize(objective, x0, method='slsqp', constraints=constraints)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this question nor your code. What are you minimizing? Where is the function you are minimizing. The error you are receiving is because there is a difference between a mathematical function (which scipy will minimize) versus a python function (which you are calling). Furthermore, x0  and x (which I assume is your list of values) are not defined in your above code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a typical form of coding an optimization problem in python using `scipy` that is represented here: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXHvC_FGx24] . objective function is defined in `objective` and constraints in `constraint`. My issue in this code is the calculation of sum variables which are computed throughout a loop. I want to know how to calculate such values in an optimization problem.

Comment: Objective is a python function that just returns a singular value (sum), it is not a mathematical function. If you are trying to calculate the sum of variables, then give the equation of a sum of variables.

Answer (score 0):

looked at the video you referenced, think you may have misunderstood a couple of things. I'll start with just a basic example to get you started.

If we take the below code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x):
    x1=x[0]
    x2=x[1]
    x3=x[2]
    x4=x[3]
    return x1+x2+x3+x4

x0=(1,1,1,1)
solution=minimize(objective,x0)
```

Simple setup. You see the **python function** objective is returning a **math function**. That math function is what you are minimizing. Note how all your variables are defined by calling the value of a list of values (x0 in this case). Thus x1 is x0[0], x2 is x0[1], etc.

In your above example, you don't define x0, and you don't have an equation. Finally, sum is a python function (it takes the sum of a list). Instead, to do what you wish to do, lets rewrite the above using a for loop now:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def objective(x):
    equation = 0
    for i in range(4):
        equation += x[i]
    return equation

x0=np.ones(4)
solution=minimize(objective,x0)
```

This will give you the exact same output as above; however now you can see I've changed sum to equation (now you won't get issues with built in python functions), and you've now defined your variables). I'm not going to go through all your code, but I hope this example clears enough up that it gets you going.

If you want 1000s values of x, just give x0 an array of 1000 values.

Edit:

To resolve the issue in the 2nd part of your code:

Presuming you fixed using sum. Again, constraints is a dict where you input a function (mathematical). I don't get the error that you are getting, so I don't know where that is coming from. But you can create a constraint function using your above example.

```
def constraints(x):
    constraint = []
    for i in range(4):
        value = 0
        for j in range(4):
            value += 10-j*x[i]
        constraint.append(value)
    return constraint


x0=np.ones(4)
con={'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraints}
sol = minimize(objective, x0, method='slsqp', constraints=con)
```

Edit 2:
You can use the exact same ideology above to create a 2nd constraint:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def objective(x):
    equation = 0
    for i in range(4):
        equation += x[i]
    return equation

def constraints(x):
    constraint = []
    for i in range(4):
        value = 0
        for j in range(4):
            value += 10-j*x[i]
        constraint.append(value)
    return constraint

def constraints2(x):
    constraint2 = []
    for a in range(4):
        value = 0
        for b in range(4):
            value += 5-a*x[b]
        constraint2.append(value)
    return constraint2

x0=np.ones(4)
con={'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraints}
con2={'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraints2}
combined=[con,con2]
sol = minimize(objective, x0, method='slsqp', constraints=combined)
```

This works without any problems or errors, so again, I don't see the problem you are having.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have still an error. It doesn't have problem with objective function, it seems that the error is related to the constraints definition. Even before running the program, I have error `Expected type 'Optional[dict]', got '(x: {__getitem__}) -> List[Union[Dict[str, Union[str, (...) -> Union[int, Any]]], Dict[str, Union[str, ...]], Dict[str, ...], ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ...]]' instead ` for calling `constraints` throughout this line: `sol = minimize(objective, x0, method='slsqp', constraints=constraints)`

Comment: I edited my above answer to also include your constraints. If this has answered your question, please don't forget to accept the we close this question.

Comment: It was great! But, I have two categories of constraints (eq, ineq). Thus, I have `con1={'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraints1}` and `con2={'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraints2}` and I define a list: `con=[con1, con2]`. I call `sol = minimize(objective, x0, method='slsqp', constraints=con)`. Although it is mentioned in scipy website that `constraints` in `minimize` function could be a dictionary or a list of dictionaries, I face with error:`Expected type 'Optional[dict]', got 'List[Union[Dict[str, Union[str, (x: Any) -> List[Union[..., Any]]]], Dict[str, Union[str, (...) -> ...]]]]' instead `

Comment: Yes, you can have a list of dictionaries. In the edit I made, I have made a list of dicts and used that as the constrained. One ineq, one eq just as you stated.